# Importar arquivos PHP através da URL invés do caminho do disco

Tags: php, apache

Quando utilizo uma arquitetura como o MVC em um projeto PHP separando os `models`, `controllers`, `services`, `views` muitas vezes utilizando as funções `include` ou `require` a aplicação se perde ao importar os arquivos PHP localizados em outros diretórios, e para isso é preciso passar o caminho do disco completo da localização do arquivo, a fim de evitar que um arquivo PHP dentro do diretório `model` ao ser importado seja procurado em `/controllers/model` em que este problema ocorre frequentemente ao voltar diretórios (`../`) por exemplo.

Gostaria de saber se é possível importar esses arquivos utilizando a URL invés do caminho do disco pelo fato de não precisar ficar entrando ou voltando em cada diretório.

Assim poderia importar simplesmente passando: `/controllers/TerceiroController.class`, por exemplo, ou `localhost/projeto/controllers/TerceiroController.class` invés de `/var/www/html/...`

Answer (score 1):

Padronize com o uso do autoloader no padrão PSR-4: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Para exemplificar, a ideia do conceito é usar namespace para facilitar a montagem de uma rota.

O recurso de namespace está disponível a partir do PHP 5.3.0.

Exemplos: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/

Comment: O que esta ocorrendo que estão negativando nossa pergunta e respostas? Desconhecia sobre isso +1

Comment: É a sede de ranking que anda habitando alguns usuários daqui.

Comment: Tem algum repositório no Github para indicar que utilize o recurso de namespace inclusive?

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode fazer isso simplesmente porque PHP é uma linguagem de script do lado do servidor.

Você pode usar recursos de um arquivo em outra URL, geralmente quando é passado por POST, isso seria uma API de algum serviço, ou até mesmo pegar o retorno (output) de alguma página, por exemplo.

Porém não é possível, fazer isso que você quer, a partir do momento que você usa http:// (mesmo que omitisse e coloca-se somente a URL externa), você já não estaria mais do "lado" do servidor.

Para resolver o seu problema, declare uma constante usando `define('RAIZ_PROJETO', dirname(__FILE__))` na index, como ela será global você poderá usar para pegar o caminho, como `require_once(RAIZ_PROJETO.'/models/seuModel.php')`

**Alerta**: Criar constantes globais e usar em todo seu projeto pode criar um alto acoplamento, ou seja, deixar suas classes muito dependentes.

Você pode criar uma classe para encalpsular essa informação e usar a injeção de dependência, como se trata de um MVC, é provável que você tenha que fazer isso em algum ponto de seu projeto, seja com arquivos de configuração ou algo que você precisa ter acesso em vários pontos mas não quer criar uma dependência direta.

E também não faz mal usar uma constante, você pode, mas tem esse lado negativo.

O lado negativo de criar uma classe e usar DI seria o trabalho de programar tudo.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua contribuição, dei +1 pra tirar esse negativo. Gostei da alteração que você fez mencionando uma solução para o problema.

Comment: Sem problemas @GiancarloAbelGiulian, um conselho extra que posso te dar é evitar usar somente "nome.class" para seus models e controllers, coloque uma extensão PHP no final, há servidores que são mau configurados que ao usuário poderia tentar acessar esse arquivo e ele seria baixado. O recomendado é proteger do acesso direto à esse arquivo, mas já seria de grande ajuda colocar um .php no final. É claro, também não é obrigação, essa é uma sugestão minha para seu projeto. Também estou trabalhando em um projeto MVC, fico grato em poder ajudar.

Comment: Na verdade me esqueci de colocar o `.php` no final hehe valeu