# Como funciona namespaces no PHP?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, namespace, php-autoload

Os [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rationale.php) foram implementados a partir da versão PHP 5.3.0, como uma forma de "encapsular itens".

Na verdade nunca entendi o real conceito dele, e sempre me confundo com [autoload de classes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Alguém poderia me explicar, de forma simples, como funciona [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rationale.php), por que eles são utilizados e se eles possuem algo com [autoload de classes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php)?

Exemplo:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers; // usando namespace
use App\User;  // usando autoload
```

Comment: Uma das respostas nessa minha pergunta fala sobre ele e tem alguns exemplos inclusive: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101738/20555, mas ainda não vi muito a fundo e sua pergunta irá me ajudar também. +1

Comment: Organizar código, evitar conflito de nome de funções... evitar risco de colisão. É usado para evitar definições conflitantes e introduzir uma maior flexibilidade e organização em sua base de código. Para usar, o programador precisa ser muito organizado, pois nada adianta usar o recurso sem ter o conhecimento sólido em OOP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Os namespaces são úteis principalmente para evitar colisão de nomes.

Foram implementados no PHP 5.3.

É muito comum ver bibliotecas mais antigos do PHP utilizando um padrão que consiste em utilizar `underline` no nome de classes, para evitar conflitos.

Isso era necessário pois, como foram surgindo muitas bibliotecas, os nomes começaram a ficar "limitados" por conta de poder haver colisões de nomes em comum.

Um grande exemplo é criar uma classe chamada `Client`. Pelo menos quase todas bibliotecas que instalei em um projeto têm esse nome. É aí que entra os namespaces.

Podemos ver um exemplo em como se resolvia esse problema antigamente.

Exemplo em versões antigas:

```
 Zend_Server_Client
```

Versões novas:

```
 Zend\Server\Client
```

Em versões do PHP 5.6 eles se tornam ainda mais útil, já que com a nova funcionalidade do `use function`, tornou-se mais fácil ter também um repositório de funções.

Exemplo:

```
 class WallaceMaxters\Helpers;

 function print_r($valor)
 {
     echo '<pre>';
     \print_r($valor);
     echo '</pre>';
 }
```

Essa função que criei chamada `print_r` não terá colisão com `print_r` por conta do namespace. Porém para usá-la em versões anteriores ao `php 5.6`, você teria que fazer algo como:

```
WallaceMaxters\Helpers\print_r($_POST);
```

Ou ainda:

```
 use WallaceMaxters\Helpers as h;

h\print_r($_POST);
```

Porém no PHP 5.6, assim como as classes, é possível criar um `alias` local para aquela função.

```
use function WallaceMaxters\Helpers\print_r as pr

pr($_POST);
```

## Autoload

O autoload de classes é uma funcionalidade adicionada para que as classes sejam carregadas (`include` e `require`) automaticamente assim que instanciadas.

Assim, ao invés de você ter que incluir toda vez uma classe que vai instanciar, você simplesmente defina uma regra global para o carregamento da classe.

Um exemplo disso é o [PSR4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), ao qual eu amo profundamente.

Padrão que é amplamente utilizado nas bibliotecas que podem ser instaladas pelo [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/);

## Padrões

O padrão que a maioria dos repositórios utilizam para as suas bibliotecas, quanto ao uso do namespace é :

```
NomeDoFornecedor\NomeDaBiblioteca\NomeDaClasse
```

Exemplo:

```
namesace Laravel\Database;

class Eloquent {}
```

Comment: me ajuda nessa aí, Brother. Tenho que voltar do almoço kkkkkkkkk

Comment: Bibliotecas antigas não usavam PSR-0. Ele já nasceu quando já existia namespaces. Utilizar o `_` eram utilizados bem antes da PSR-0 e ele só suportava esse tipo de classes para manter compatibilidade com códigos muito antigos.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação @gmsantos. Eu não sou da época anterior ao php 5. Isso é o que presuponho quando vejo classes antigas

Comment: Vale uma edição em sua resposta, para evitar que informações erradas sejam passadas adiante.

Comment: Cara viajei mesmo, desculpa aí. Confundi a questão do psr-0

Comment: Value @gmsantos. Cê tava sumido, cara

Answer (score 10):

Namespaces são utilizados para agrupar itens(classes, constantes ou funções no php) geralmente isso é determinado pela afinidade entre eles. Assim como uma classe agrupa propriedades e métodos para resolver um problema(responsabilidade única) com o namescape acontece o mesmo porém em um escopo maior, em outras palavras ele define quais são as 'funcionalidades' daquele modulo.

O namespace do php não é tão pratico quanto os packges do java, uma vantagem seria carregar por exemplo o módulo inteiro de i18n que prove classes para formatação de datas, valores de moeda etc ou o módulo de persistência que fornece várias classes para leitura e escrita de informações em diferentes tipos de tecnologia como banco de dados relacionais, NOSQL, LDAP etc.

No PHP7 existe uma forma levemente melhorada de carregar um grupo de classe

```
use app\persistencia\{DBRelaciona, DBNoSQL, LDAP};
```

[Manual - namespaces v7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)