# Diferenças entre as sintaxes de namespaces

Tags: php, c#, sintaxe, namespace

Conheço duas formas de declarar um namespace:

```php
// Comum
namespace Example\Class\Method;

class ExampleClass {...}

// Outro, similar a sintaxe C# (classe dentro do namespace)
namespace Example\Class\Method
{
    class ExampleClass {...}
}
```

Existe alguma diferença entre ambas?

Comment: Não entendi bem o que quer saber e a sintaxe do C# está errada. Quer saber sobre a chave e o ponto e vírgula?

Comment: Sim o que eu quis dizer era com a classe dentro do namespace assim como no C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada linguagem tem seu jeito de lidar com as coisas. Se fosse isso, nem sei se a pergunta faria sentido. Nesse caso não é só a sintaxe que é diferente, a semântica também.

Em PHP a definição vale para todo o arquivo, até achar uma nova definição de `namespace`. Ele deve ser feita sempre no início do arquivo. Pelo menos nesta sintaxe.

[Pergunta com mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104420/101).

[Documentação sobre a definição](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php). [Sobre o uso múltiplo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php).

O Wallace diz em comentário que pode ser diferente, mas não vi uma referência sobre o assunto. Odeio linguagens que documentam errado ou de forma confusa. E eu só confio na documentação (quando ela não está errada também). Usar algo que funciona mas não está documentado é a última coisa que um programador deve fazer.

As chaves também funcionam no PHP.

Tanto o C# quanto o PHP só pode ter tipos como membros do `namespace`.

Em C# os membros de um determinando *namespace* estão dentro das chaves que o delimita. Portanto é possível ter mais que um *namespace* por arquivo.

[Pergunta com mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101).

[Documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx).

A sintaxe correta do C#:

```
namespace Example {
    class ExampleClass {...}
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Namespace.cs).

Não se coloca o nome da classe, menos ainda do método no nome do `namespace`.

Se fosse para ter um nome multi nível seria assim:

```
namespace Nome.OutroNome.MaisUmNome
```

Mas note que no fundo essa separação é virtual. O nome é uma coisa só. Não fica um `namespace` dentro de outro. É perfeita possível ter este `namespace` sem ter o `Nome`. Vide pergunta *linkada* acima para mais detalhes.

Em C# 10 é possível declarar o *namespace* para todo o arquivo usando um `;` em vez de ter que colocar o código pertencente a ele dentro de um bloco com chaves.

Comment: No PHP aceita dos dois jeitos :p

Comment: Pode ser, tem referência sobre isto? Mas se for do jeito da pergunta, acho que não pode ter mais que um, pelo menos é o q está na documentação. Há alguma erro nela? http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

Comment: Pode sim. Desde que no script só contenha definições de classes e namespaces :p

Comment: Mas tem documentação dizendo isto?

Comment: Eu nem olho a documentação as vezes, só testo. Tem muita coisa que não fala na documentação do PHP. Mas posso dar uma conferida.

Comment: Se eu utilizar apenas `namespace {...}` é global, como assim? Deveria fazer outra pergunta sobre isto?

Comment: @José onde viu isto? Documentação? PHP ou C#? Acho que é caso pra outra pergunta sim.

Comment: @bigown Sim na documentação, http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php é só descer até chegar perto da notas contribuintes, a última parte da documentação exemplo #4

Comment: @José resumidamente é um `namepace` global mesmo, como ele não tem nome, está sempre disponível (afinal não tem como importar algo que não tem nome). Podemos dizer que tudo que não etá explicitamente declarado, está neste `namespace`.

Answer (score 2):

Não existe nenhuma diferença entre elas.

No PHP aceita a declaração de namespaces com chaves e sem chaves.

No caso do uso das chaves, tudo que for colocado ali dentro, fará parte do namespace que você declarou com elas.

```
namespace A {    
   class A {}
}

namespace B {    
    class A{}
}
```

Já no caso da falta das chaves, os elementos declarados farão parte do namespace, até que você declare outro.

```
namespace A;

class A {}

class B {}

namespace B;

class A{}
```

https://ideone.com/lcqvu8

Já  no C# sempre deve ser com as chaves.