# Auto Load de classes no PHP

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um mini-framework para usar em minhas aplicações e fiz o auto load de classes dessa forma :

```
function __autoload($Class) {

    $cDir = ['Conn', 'Helpers', 'Models'];
    $iDir = null;

    foreach ($cDir as $dirName):
        if (!$iDir && file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php') && !is_dir(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php')):
            include_once (__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php');
            $iDir = true;
        endif;
    endforeach;

    if (!$iDir):
        trigger_error("Não foi possível incluir {$Class}.class.php", E_USER_ERROR);
        die;
    endif;

}
```

Há como optimizar mais esse código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma abaixo, primeiramente melhorando a legibilidade do código, usando nomes mais simples para ficar mais fácil sua compreensão e usando a sintaxe normal do `if` e `foreach`.

Depois usando a função `spl_autoload_register` ao ínveis do método mágico `__autoload`, pois usando a função `spl_autoload_register`, você tem a possibilidade de registrar mais de uma função de autoload para suas classes.

Lembrando também que o método mágico `__autoload`, pode vir a não mais existir nas próximas versões do PHP, pois essa função está obsoleta de acordo com sua documentação.

```
<?php

// AUTO LOAD DE CLASSES ####################
function myAutoload($className) {

    $directoryNames = ['Conn', 'Helpers', 'Models'];
    $includedClass = false;

    foreach ($directoryNames as $directoryName) {

        $path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $directoryName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $className . '.class.php';

        if (!$directoryName && file_exists($path) && !is_dir($path)) {

            include_once ($path);
            $includedClass = true;

        };

    }

    if (!$includedClass) {
        trigger_error("Não foi possível incluir {$className}.class.php", E_USER_ERROR);
        die;
    }

}

//Usando essa função você pode usar mais de uma função para autoload.
spl_autoload_register("myAutoload");
```

Você também ao ínves de criar sua própria função de autoload, você poderia usar uma especificação já pronta que é a [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) para carregamentos de classes no PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Pode otimizar eliminando a técnica que itera um array de diretórios.

```
$cDir = array('pasta1', 'pasta2', 'pasta3')
foreach ($cDir as $dirName) {
    // aqui vai repetir, buscando nos diretórios registrados até encontrar.
    // isso é redundante e pode ser evitado
}
```

Uma sugestão é padronizar conforme recomendações do [php-fig.org](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Você deve ter visto em algum lugar algo como PHP PSR, PSR4, etc.

PSR significa -> PHP Standards Recommendation.

<sub>Não é uma regra da qual todos devem seguir. É opcional.</sub>

## Otimizando com PSR4

Para otimizar o seu autoload, poderia fazer algo no padrão PSR4:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    // project-specific namespace prefix
    $prefix = 'Foo\\Bar\\';

    // base directory for the namespace prefix
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/';

    // does the class use the namespace prefix?
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }

    // get the relative class name
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

    // if the file exists, require it
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

É apenas isso. A única coisa que você modificaria é o prefixo do seu namespace e a base dos arquivos.

```
$prefix = 'Foo\\Bar\\';
```

Caso o seu namespace for `Qualquer\Outro\Nome`, ficaria assim

```
$prefix = 'Qualquer\\Outro\\Nome\\';
```

A base dos arquivos é definida nesse trecho

```
$base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/';
```

Apenas configure a base de acordo com o seu projeto.

Obviamente você terá que usar namespace no seus arquivos que deseja autocarregar.

A nomenclatura dos diretórios e arquivos devem seguir o mesmo padrão do nome da classe.

Exemplo, quando instanciar uma classe:

```
new \Foo\Bar\Baz\Qux;
```

O autoload, do exemplo acima, vai reconhecer o trecho do prefixo do namespace: `\Foo\Bar` e com trabalhará com o restante `Baz\Qux`

Formando assim, o local de onde está o arquivo

```
/www/site/src/Baz/Qux.php
```

Essa lógica elimina todo aquele custo de iteração de um array para percorrer diretórios que na maioria das vezes é desnecessário e ainda corre o risco de colidir com um nome igual em diretórios diferentes.

Essa técnica com array foi útil para uma época onde o PHP ainda não possuía o recurso de [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php), disponível a partir do PHP5.3.

Relacionado ao namespace: [Como funciona namespaces no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/como-funciona-namespaces-no-php)

Answer (score -1):

```
                $pastas = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'];
                foreach($diretorios as $pacth)
                {
                    foreach(glob("asset/$pacth/*.class.php") as $filename){
                    require_once $filename;
                }
            }
```