# namespace com php

Tags: php, namespace

Estou querendo me aprofundar mais no `namespace`, porém das formas que estou tentando, está dando ***erro***. Segue abaixo as duas formas:

Minha classe que fica dentro do diretório **classes/classe.php**

```
namespace minhaClasse;
class classe
{
  public function testes(){
    return "ok.. retornou!";
  }
}
```

O arquivo index.php que fica no diretório raiz

```
<?php
use minhaClasse\classe;
$ver = new classe();
echo $ver->testes();
?>
```

Quando faço isso, aparece o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Class 'minhaClasse\classe' not found in...

Então modifiquei para essa forma o index.php

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();
use minhaClasse\classe;
$ver = new classe();
echo $ver->testes();
```

Aí aparece esse erro:

> Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class minhaClasse\classe could not be
>   loaded in...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para funcionar esse tipo de código e carregar automaticamente por [namespace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rationale.php) os diretórios devem seguir o mesmo nome que estão no [namespace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rationale.php), no seu caso já tem um problema o diretório deveria ser `minhaClasse/classe.php` ou então o [namespace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rationale.php) deveria ser `use classes\classe;` (dentro da classe somente `namespace classes;`) qualquer uma das opções podem funcionar.

Edite o [namespace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rationale.php) da sua `classe` para `classes` e para utilizar `use classes\classe`:

```
namespace classes;

class classe
{
  public function testes(){
    return "ok.. retornou!";
  }
}
```

e no seu código, faça alteração no [namespace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rationale.php), que vai funcionar:

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();

use classes\classe;

$ver = new classe();
echo $ver->testes();
```

<sub>***Observação:*** os nomes do `namespace` e `pastas` (que devem ter o mesmo nome) poderiam seguir nomes mais simples possivel e sem fazer referencia a nomes que podem dificultar a leitura, isso pode causar confusão `classes\classe`</sub>

---

***Exemplo minimo:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da classe `Car` é o seguinte (*observe o `namespace` e o nome do `diretório` na imagem*):

```
<?php

namespace Novic;

class Car 
{
    private $active = 1;

    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }
    public function setActive($value)
    {
        return $this->active = $value;
    }
}
```

dentro da pasta anterior (ou seja, na pasta ***test1***) foi criado um `index.php` com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();

use Novic\Car;

$car = new Car();
echo $car->getActive();
```

O `namespace` utilizado `Novic\Car` referente a pasta e a classe.

---

***Leitura:***

Tem aqui no site [Como funciona namespaces no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104420/54880) e também sobre [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), que é bem utilizado.

***Referencias:***

- [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php)
- [spl_autoload_extensions](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-extensions.php)
- [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: Funcionou Virgílio. Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos e indicação de leitura.