# O meu código é orientado a objeto?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um código e gostaria de saber se o mesmo é um código orientado a objetos. Segue a estrutura. Trabalho com 3 arquivos.

1º chama `save.php`, segue o código:

```
include_once('dao.php');
include_once('modelo.php');
$post = new Post();
$post->setDescricao($_POST['custo_descricao_html']);
$post->setMes($_POST['custo_mes_atual']);
$post->setLocal($_POST['custo_local_html']);
$post->setPreco($_POST['custo_custo_html']);
$post->setObservacao($_POST['custo_observacao_html']);
$post->setColaborador_id($_POST['colaborador_logado_custo']);


$dao = new DaoCusto();

if ($_POST['custo_controle_html'] == 0) {
 $post->setId(rand(0, time()));
 $resultado = $dao->insert($post);
 echo($resultado == 'salvo') ? '0' : $resultado;
} else {
 $post->setId($_POST['custo_idUpdate_html']);
 $resultado = $dao->update($post);
 echo($resultado == 'salvo') ? '0' : $resultado;
}
```

2ª arquivo que faço os `gets` e `sets`, `modelo.php`:

```
<?php

    class Post {

    private $id;
    private $descricao;
    private $mes;
    private $local;
    private $preco;
    private $observacao;
    private $colaborador_id;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescricao() {
        return $this->descricao;
    }

    public function setDescricao($descricao) {
        $this->descricao = $descricao;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getMes() {
        return $this->mes;
    }

    public function setMes($mes) {
        $this->mes = $mes;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLocal() {
        return $this->local;
    }

    public function setLocal($local) {
        $this->local = $local;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPreco() {
        return $this->preco;
    }

    public function setPreco($preco) {
        $this->preco = $preco;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getObservacao() {
        return $this->observacao;
    }

    public function setObservacao($observacao) {
        $this->observacao = $observacao;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getColaborador_id() {
        return $this->colaborador_id;
    }

    public function setColaborador_id($colaborador_id) {
        $this->colaborador_id = $colaborador_id;
        return $this;
    }

    }
```

E o terceiro arquivo que é onde realizo meu `CRUD` , `dao.php`

```
     <?php

     require_once '../../../conexao/conexao.php';
     require_once 'modelo.php';

    class DaoCusto {

    public static $instance;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function insert(Post $custo) {
        try {


            $sql = "INSERT INTO  tb_custo (custo_id , custo_descricao , custo_mes , custo_local , custo_preco , custo_observacao , colaborador_colaborador_id)   values (:custo_id , :custo_descricao , :custo_mes , :custo_local , :custo_preco , :custo_observacao  , :colaborador_colaborador_id)";

            $p_sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);

            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_id', $custo->getId());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_descricao', $custo->getDescricao());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_mes', $custo->getMes());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_local', $custo->getLocal());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_preco', $custo->getPreco());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_observacao', $custo->getObservacao());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':colaborador_colaborador_id', $custo->getColaborador_id());

            return ($p_sql->execute()) ? 'salvo' : false;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return 'Erro, contate o suporte!Código:' . $e->getCode() . 'Mensagem:' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function Update(Post $custo) {
        try {


            $sql = "UPDATE tb_custo SET   custo_descricao= :custo_descricao , custo_mes= :custo_mes , custo_local= :custo_local , custo_preco= :custo_preco , custo_observacao= :custo_observacao , colaborador_colaborador_id= :colaborador_colaborador_id WHERE custo_id= :custo_id ";
            $p_sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);

            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_descricao', $custo->getDescricao());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_mes', $custo->getMes());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_local', $custo->getLocal());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_preco', $custo->getPreco());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_observacao', $custo->getObservacao());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':colaborador_colaborador_id', $custo->getColaborador_id());
            $p_sql->bindValue(':custo_id', $custo->getId());

            return ($p_sql->execute()) ? 'salvo' : false;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return 'Erro, contate o suporte!Código:' . $e->getCode() . 'Mensagem:' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

   }
```

Essa estrutura é orientada a objetos?

Comment: É sim, ficou com dúvida em algum ponto? desconfiou que não era pq?

Comment: Está faltando alguns ajustes ... mas, você separou a classe modelo da classe operação ... é bacana ir nesse caminho. Precisa ver a classe Conexão. Uma coisa não coloque a classe conexão na classe DAO. coloque ela como include no inicio do seu código.

Comment: Eu estava vendo na net e vi outra maneiras de se montar uma estrutura OO , ai fiquei com duvida nessa minha estrutura.

Comment: Valeu o feedback Virgilio Novic

Comment: @MarlonCastro está faltando alguns detalhes, mas, está no caminho, poderia ser melhorado com `namespace` se assim preferir algumas, coisas que acho legal implementar, mas, cara tá legal.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163660/namespace-com-php/163662#163662 dê uma lida nisso também @MarlonCastro

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção @VirgilioNovic , vou estudar sobre tudo isso :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na medida do que é possível fazer [orientação a objeto em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101), a classe `Post` é bem OOP, só não é mais porque não está usando herança e polimorfismo, ainda bem. Há encapsulamento e alguma abstração. O ganho de ter feito desta forma me parece próximo de zero, mas não dá para dizer que tem algo errado. Um *array* associativo teria sido muito mais simples, o que me faz pensar que o ganho possa ser considerado negativo.

`DaoCusto` é um pouco menos. Tudo que é estático é menos orientado a objeto, mas é um pouco. Teria sido muito mais simples criar uma função simples. Está forçando o uso de um mecanismo que não cabe aí. Funciona, tem gente que gosta de fazer assim, mas não há ganho, pelo contrário.

A questão é: qual a relevância disto? O objetivo é seguir uma fórmula sem entender bem porque ou fazer algo que ajude o código ficar melhor? OOP não faz o código ficar melhor por mágica e há casos que ele pode piorar o que está fazendo. Não parece ser tanto o seu caso, quando precisou ser pragmático, até foi, pelo menos em partes.

Veja: [O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101)

Entenda que [orientação a objeto é algo secundário para a programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101). Em [PHP mais ainda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108227/101).

Comment: Exatamente , fiz isso no pouco que aprendi vendo na net. Mas estava pesquisando e vi coisas mais aprofundados, e queria saber se esse codigo pode ser considerado OO , mas valeu pelos links , vou estuda-los.

Comment: "e há casos que ele pode piorar o que está fazendo" - Em PHP eu diria que é o que mais acontece.

Comment: Um código orientado a objetos procura reaproveitar comportamentos aumentando a coesão do código que é escrito. Se você tem uma classe DAO que recebe um objeto concreto, toda vez que você for implementar um novo terá que escrever uma nova classe com códigos praticamente idênticos, pois como o Maniero disse: não há vantagem em implementar isso dessa forma. Um array associativo passado para uma abstração que recebe um objeto genérico e não um em especifico seria mais adequando e ajudaria a remover essa granularidade desnecessária.Tome como exemplo uma abstração vantajosa para esse exemplo os ORMs