# Tudo que consigo fazer em POO eu consigo fazer em PE?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, paradigma-de-programação, programação-estruturada

Consigo fazer tudo ou muda alguma coisa? Tenho limites em programação estruturada nos quais em POO eu não tenho?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim, [qualquer linguagem de programação pode fazer tudo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101). Agora, cada [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) tem seu jeito de organizar, então nem sempre pode-se fazer do mesmo jeito. Mais ainda, com algumas linguagens e uso de determinados paradigmas é possível que tarefas específicas sejam mais fáceis de fazer em um paradigma do que em outro.

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, nem tudo fica melhor orientado a objeto.

Aproveito para dizer que não há dicotomia entre [orientação a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101) e [programação estruturada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122430/101). A programação estruturada diz respeito ao algoritmo em si, e OOP não. Na verdade o que você deve estar chamando de estruturado é o [paradigma imperativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101). O fato é que programamos imperativamente, e claro, estruturadamente na maior parte do tempo.

Em alguns aspectos da estrutura de dados e como organizar as partes dos algoritmos, mas não o algoritmo em si, fazemos orientado a objeto. Me impressiona como as pessoas querem tanto fazer OO ou dizem que fazem sem sequer saberem o que isso significa.

Existe o imperativo estruturado e não estruturado. Hoje praticamente só é usado o estruturado, a não ser que esteja usando Assembly.

Mesmo [linguagens não criadas para uso da orientação a objeto pode-se programar assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101).

Particularmente acho que OOP em PHP faz pouco sentido, mas hoje quase todo mundo usa PHP onde não deveria. Se é pra fazer algo assim e gosta mesmo de PHP, então vai de [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101).

Relacionado:

- [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101)
- [Significado da terminologia "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101)
- [PHP mistura códigos de orientação a objetos e linguagem procedural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101)
- [Vantagens de usar PHP Orientado a Objetos? Onde usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108227/101)
- [O meu código é orientado a objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170017/101)
- [Qual o overhead de utilizar orientação a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50273/101)

Se pesquisar tem bem mais relacionados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).