# Criar função sacar()

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou com um problema na minha lógica aqui, preciso criar uma função sacar(), mas ela tem os seguintes requisitos:

• A conta precisa existir

• Ela precisa ter saldo maior que 0

• O saqui não pode ser maior que o valor que tem na conta

Como faço isso? Tentei fazer mas estou com dificuldade nessa parte.

Meu código:

```
<?php


class ContaNoBanco {
    private $numConta;
    public $tipoConta;
    public $donoConta;
    private $saldoConta;
    private $statusConta;

    private function abrirConta(){
        if($this->statusConta) {
             echo'Você ja tem uma conta aberta, de número: ' . $this->getNumConta();
        }
        else {
            $this->statusConta = true;
        }
        switch ($this->tipoConta) {
            case 0:
                $this->setTipoConta('CC');
                $this->setSaldoConta($this->saldoConta + 50);
            case 1:
                $this->setTipoConta('CP');
                $this->setSaldoConta($this->saldoConta + 150);
            break;
        }
    }

    private function fecharConta(){
        if($this->saldoConta === 0) {
        $this->statusConta = false;
        }
        else if($this->statusConta < 0){
            echo'Você tem R$' . $this->getSaldoConta() . ' débitos a pagar, se regularize antes de fechar sua conta!';
        }
        else{
            echo'Você tem o saldo de R$' . $this->getSaldoConta() . ' saque o dinheiro antes de fechar sua conta!';
        }

    }


    public function depositar() {

    }

    /*public function sacar(){
        if($this->statusConta) {
            if($this->saldoConta > 0){
               if($this->setSaldoConta() > $this->saldoConta){
                   echo'Você não pode sacar mais do que ' . $this->getSaldoConta();
               }
               else {
                   $this->setSaldoConta($this->saldoConta - 50);
               }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo'A conta está fechada!';
        }
    }*/
    public function pagarMensal(){

    }

    function getNumConta() {
        return $this->numConta;
    }

    function getTipoConta() {
        return $this->tipoConta;
    }

    function getDonoConta() {
        return $this->donoConta;
    }

    function getSaldoConta() {
        return $this->saldoConta;
    }

    function getStatusConta() {
        return $this->statusConta;
    }

    function setNumConta($numConta) {
        $this->numConta = $numConta;
    }

    function setTipoConta($tipoConta) {
        $this->tipoConta = $tipoConta;
    }

    function setDonoConta($donoConta) {
        $this->donoConta = $donoConta;
    }

    function setSaldoConta($saldoConta) {
        $this->saldoConta = $saldoConta;
    }

    function setStatusConta($statusConta) {
        $this->statusConta = $statusConta;
    }


}
```

---

EDITADO

Codigo 100%

```
<?php


class ContaNoBanco {

    //Atributos
    public $numConta;
    protected $tipoConta;
    private $donoConta;
    private $saldoConta;
    private $statusConta;

    //Métodos

    public function abrirConta($t){
        $this->setTipoConta($t);
        $this->setStatusConta(true);
        if($t == "CC"){
            $this->setSaldoConta(50);
        }
        else if($t == "CP"){
            $this->setSaldoConta(150);
        }
    }

    public function fecharConta(){
        if($this->getSaldoConta() === 0) {
            $this->setStatusConta(false);
            echo"<p>Conta de {$this->getDonoConta()} fechada com sucesso!</p>";
        }
        else if($this->getSaldoConta() < 0){
            echo"Você tem R$' . $this->getSaldoConta() . ' débitos a pagar, se regularize antes de fechar sua conta!";
        }
        else {
            echo"<p>Voce tem o saldo de R$" . $this->getSaldoConta() . "saque o dinheiro antes de fechar sua conta!<p/>";
        }

    }

    public function depositar($v) {
        if ($this->getStatusConta()){
            $this->setSaldoConta($this->getSaldoConta() + $v);
            echo"<p>Deposito de R$ $v na conta de " . $this->getDonoConta() . "</p>";
        }
        else {
            echo"<p>Você não tem uma conta no banco!</p>";
        }
    }

    public function sacar($v){
        if($this->getStatusConta()) {
            if($this->getSaldoConta() >= $v){
                $this->setSaldoConta($this->getSaldoConta() - $v);
                echo"<p>Saque de R$$v autorizado na conta de " . $this->getDonoConta() . "</p>";
            }
            else {
                echo"<p>Saldo insuficiente!</p>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo"Essa conta não existe!";
        }
    }

    public function pagarMensal(){
        if($this->getStatusConta() === false) {
            echo"Conta não existe!";
        }
        if($this->getTipoConta() == "CC") {
            $v = 12;
        }
        else if ($this->getTipoConta() == "CP"){
            $v = 20;
        }
        if ($this->getStatusConta()){
            $this->setSaldoConta($this->getSaldoConta() - $v);
            echo"<p>Mensalidade de $v debitada na conta de " .$this->getDonoConta() . "</p>";
        }
        else {
            echo'<p>Problemas com a conta!</p>';
        }
    }

    //Métodos Especiais

    function __construct(){
        $this->setSaldoConta(0);
        $this->setStatusConta(false);
        echo'<p>Conta criada com sucesso!</p>';
    }

    function getNumConta() {
        return $this->numConta;
    }

    function getTipoConta() {
        return $this->tipoConta;
    }

    function getDonoConta() {
        return $this->donoConta;
    }

    function getSaldoConta() {
        return $this->saldoConta;
    }

    function getStatusConta() {
        return $this->statusConta;
    }

    function setNumConta($numConta) {
        $this->numConta = $numConta;
    }

    function setTipoConta($tipoConta) {
        $this->tipoConta = $tipoConta;
    }

    function setDonoConta($donoConta) {
        $this->donoConta = $donoConta;
    }

    function setSaldoConta($saldoConta) {
        $this->saldoConta = $saldoConta;
    }

    function setStatusConta($statusConta) {
        $this->statusConta = $statusConta;
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual é o problema, qual a dúvida?

Comment: Desculpe. É que não sei como, verificar, na hora de sacar, pra bloquear se for maior que o saldo.

Comment: O que é isso? `$this->setSaldoConta($this->saldoConta - 50);` Só pode sacar 50? Não pode sacar um valor arbitrário?

Comment: Isso é quando abrir a conta. Só esqueci do +=. É que quando abrir, a CC já inicia com 50 e a CP com 100. No lugar de + ali é +=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só te dar uma dica inicial: isso parece exercício e está ok fazer assim, em aplicações reais que precisam de OOP em geral o problema é muito mais complexo que isto e a forma de fazer é bem diferente.

Até usando a [pergunta anterior sobre OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101), esse código é ruim conceitualmente porque em vez dele pedir para ver se cada condição é válida ([veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101)), ele fica chamando métodos *getters* simples que não trazem ganhos algum neste código, pior, mistura o método e o atributo. Internamente não costuma ter vantagem alguma de acessar os atributos por métodos *getters* e *setters*. Como [já falei antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211768/101), para acesso público em *scripts* a vantagem é pouca, mas internamente é zero mesmo.

Outra dica é que 90% do tempo programamos imperativamente, e é preciso dominar isso muito bem antes de partir para OOP. Dá para simplificar esse código quando é impedido por algum motivo e deixa fazer apenas se passar por todos os filtros. Novamente a forma usada funciona em códigos simples, em outros pode ficar bem complicado dar manutenção. Curiosamente as pessoas tentam fazer OOP e não conseguem obter benefício no seu uso por não entenderem o que fazer, porque usar assim.

Como última dica, em aplicação real não pode tratar valor monetário como um número normal do PHP que possui ponto flutuante e gera inexatidão de cálculo.

O problema de exercícios fictícios é que eles não costumam ensinar nada útil de fato a não ser alguma construção de linguagem muito específica, o que não parece ser o objetivo do que foi proposto. Fora isto ou qualquer coisa serve ou precisa ter claro os requisitos.

## O problema

Imagino que o primeiro requisito é se a conta está ativa. Parece ok no código.

Me parece que a comparação se tem saldo deve ser com o valor a ser sacado. Onde está esse valor? Deveria ser um parâmetro no método `sacar()`? E este parâmetro que deveria ser subtraído do saldo pra ver se é maior que 0?

Já pensou que este valor de saque pode vir negativo e isto seria um erro? Tem que verificar isso também.

Percebeu também que não importa se o saldo é maior que 0? Se o saldo menos o valor a ser sacado for negativo já é condição suficiente para impedir o saque.

Não entendi a linha `$this->setSaldoConta($this->saldoConta - 50);`, só pode sacar 50?

Poderia ser assim:

```
public function sacar(){
    if ($this->statusConta) {
        echo 'A conta está fechada!';
        return;
    }
    if ($this->saldoConta - 50 < 0) {
        echo'Você não pode sacar mais do que ' . $this->$saldoConta;
        return;
    }
    $this.saldoConta -= 50;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/Withdraw.php).

Comment: Sim, é exercício do curso em vídeo, do professor Guanabara. É uma aula teórica, ele foi falando e eu digitando o código. Mas estou aprendendo os Getters, Setters e contructor, por isso fiz aseim, pôs é o que ele ensinou até agora. Sobre verificar se é maior que 0, etc, eu até tentei, está comentado, mas não deu muito certo.

Comment: É o que eu falei, usar algo onde não precisa, é aprender errado.

Comment: Chegando no meu trabalho amanhã, vou ver pelo computador, seu código bigowns, mas desde já, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Sim, ele não ensinou a fazer assim no caso, ele está ensinando sobre os métodos. Aí coloquei assim, mas obrigado, mais uma vez, amanhã eu consigo ver!

Comment: Bom dia bigown, agora estou no computador. Seu código deu certo, obrigado!!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho ótimo, só atente que dar certo e estar certo é algo muito diferente. Eu ainda acho que não está certo, apenas deu o resultado que você espera :)

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de como seria estar certo? Não precisa ser esse meu código grande não, só alguma parte dele, só pra eu entender antes de continuar o curso. Por favor, se não for incomodo.

Comment: O problema é esse, tem que reescrever tudo, e eu já percebi que continuar o curso que vai te ensinar fazer errado não vai te ajudar, tem que começar pelo começo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60460/discussion-between-lucas-carvalho-and-bigown).