# Como saber se estou programando proceduralmente em orientação a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, estilo-de-codificação, projeto-de-software, programação-estruturada

Como saber se estou programando em estilo procedural em uma linguagem orientada a objetos?

Comment: Eu diria que é entendendo totalmente o que é orientação a objeto, o que não é simples, porque existem escolas diferentes. Tem algumas perguntas que eu respondi que mais ou menos ou totalmente responde isso:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170017/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101 e ainda pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211768/101. Ainda fica a dúvida saber se o código é bom ou não :) O que mais vejo é código orientado a objeto ruim, até por não precisar ser assim. O que é diferente de nem ser OO e a pessoa achar que é.

Comment: Orientação a objetos é uma estratégia, é uma forma de pensar, que é apoiada por construções específicas em uma dada linguagem ou não. A noção de classe, objeto e herança, dentre outros, são conceitos bem estabelecidos. Se você faz uso deles de forma "adequada", então está empregando a orientação a objetos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL; DR

Pra mim se você não está usando os pilares de OOP não está fazendo OOP. E pra mim quase todo projeto que se diz OO (não programação) no fundo chama OO porque está na moda. Algumas pessoas discordam disso. Projetos coesos e não acoplados são sempre desejáveis e isto pode ser obtido no procedural, especialmente se aplicar a modularização, as pessoas tomam isso como algo de OOP simplesmente por não conhecer [paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101), só decorar a receita de bolo que acham por aí.

## Detalhando

Já respondi sobre [programação procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195069/101). Tentamos responder o que é [orientação a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101) (sobre [o termo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) pode ajudar). Note que sequer há consenso do que é isto e todo mundo acha que sua definição é a correta e a dos outros está errada. Não deixe de ver sobre [programação modular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101) porque falarei dela. Como há confusão sobre [programação estruturada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122430/101) em outras respostas leia também ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211768/101)).

Eu gosto de definição do título dessa pergunta: [Significado de "o código atuando sobre os dados" e "os dados controlando o acesso ao código"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/341597/101), acho que esta pergunta pode ser feita para você identificar o que está fazendo, não sei se ajuda tanto, mas ela é boa. E uma [análise comparando ambas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101) pode ajudar responder de forma bastante ampla.

Se quer um exemplo prático de análise tem uma pergunta: [O meu código é orientado a objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170017/101).

Então dizer o que é OOP ou não, depende um pouco de quem está lhe falando. Este é o motivo que eu acho que ninguém pode dar uma boa resposta. Talvez se seguir os [pilares de OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101) seja uma forma. Alguns dirão que não. Alguns confundirão projeto orientado a objeto com programação orientada a objeto. Ficou mais confuso? Pois é. Um dos motivos que abomino UML é porque enquanto está projetando ele [usa termos e prega coisas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) do que as pessoas usam na programação, inclusive porque desconsidera performance e características específicas da tecnologia usada.

Há correntes que pregam certas regras e outras que pregam outras. Por exemplo o polêmico uso de [*getters* e *setters*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) (é, tem que ler todos *links* lá pra entender bem), só pra citar um exemplo.

Um erro comum é misturar abstração com encapsulamento. Eu mesmo fazia muito isto e preciso revisar minhas respostas pra ver se ainda não tem nada equivocado.

O que muitos erram é em achar que usar uma classe está programando orientado a objetos. Classe por si só é uma estrutura de dados simples que tem algo semelhante em linguagens não orientadas a objetos. A maneira como cria a classe definirá se é OOP. Uma classe simples no máximo é uma programação procedural modular. E [OOP não exige ter classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142884/101).

Por aí já dá para perceber que a resposta menos votada fala de coisas sem compromisso com a acurácia. Ela não está estritamente errada, mas não quer dizer nada.

A resposta mais votada (até o momento que escrevo aqui) dá algumas regras de estilo de código (até boas no geral), mas aquilo nada tem a ver com OOP, você deve seguir aquilo em programação procedural também. Inclusive o que mais tem que entender para montar um bom *design* de código é sobre [coesão e acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101), que no fundo é a origem do SOLID (é só uma forma diferente de *marketar* o conceito original, é uma "dica Miojo") e os primeiros itens da resposta depois é resumido no último quando fala no SOLID. SOLID não é o mesmo que OOP. A resposta também não diz nada que ajude.

A resposta mais recente está cheia de erros:

- Ela acha que [ter objetos é algo exclusivo de orientação a objeto, e não é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101).
- Fala em troca de mensagens, o que não é um erro *per se*, porém hoje ninguém programa pensando nisso, é um conceito teórico que se perdeu porque não faz diferença.
- Ter um grafo de objetos tem a ver com estrutura de dados e não com OOP.
- Uma sequência de passos é algo sobre programação imperativa e não procedural.
- O resto do parágrafo sem uma definição mais clara quer dizer nada.
- Já *linkei* algo sobre coesão e acoplamento, isso é muito mais antigo e é algo aplicado a OOP ou procedural ou modular, não é exclusivo de OOP, é conceito de *design* de sistemas (e nem precisa ser de programação).
- Qualquer projeto complexo demanda esforço significativo, o problema de OOP é que se você errar na concepção não é tão fácil corrigir depois (eu já respondi para o AP sobre isso não achei em qual pergunta foi).

Acho que a presença da *tag* [programação-estruturada](/questions/tagged/programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-estruturada) pode ter ajudado na confusão.

O procedural puro hoje não é muito usado a não ser em linguagens de *script* já que ali não tem complexidade e OOP sem complexidade não faz muito sentido (falo disto em um desses *links*). Em geral usamos procedural com modular. Aí fica mais difícil ver diferenças porque o módulo pode ser uma classe.

Algumas pessoas são tão dogmáticas com OOP que se você fizer como elas querem terá um código ideológico e nem sempre atendendo as demandas reais do sistema.

Se as pessoas não entendem nem o que são essas coisas todas, acha que vão aplicar certo? OO é algo tão mal definido que as pessoas usam o termo sem nem saber se estão fazendo aquilo.

## Dicas para avaliar

Algumas pessoas falam que o fato de você acessar os métodos pelo objeto é OOP, algo assim:

```
objeto.metodo()
```

Em oposição a isto procedural:

```
metodo(objeto)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/ObjectXProcedural.ptg).

Jura que só este detalhe é programar orientado a objeto?

Outros dizem que é quase isso, mas olhando do lado da classe, então falam que são os métodos estarem junto do estado. De fato é um jeito único que o "paradigma OO tem, então até poderia, mas só isso define? Talvez. Mas alguns tendem a colocar junto coisas que não deveriam estar lá. Por isso começaram criar regras para fazer objetos menores, tão pequenos que fica claro que o objeto coeso é praticamente não ter objetos (ter alguns claro, em todos paradigmas existem objetos).

Mas o pessoal fala muito em fazer orientação a objeto do jeito certo. Aí tem um conjunto de regrinhas que o pessoal fala, nem todas são consensuais, mas essencialmente todas são regras de bom *design* que devem ser aplicados em qualquer paradigma. Novamente, o fato das pessoas não entenderem isso diz muito como aprendem de um jeito muito torto.

Há quem diga que é simular o mundo real, mas hoje muita gente considera isso uma bobagem, inclusive porque isso quer dizer pouco, além de não conseguirmos fazer isso, o mundo é muito mais complexo.

Há quem diga que só o encapsulamento importa, porque o Alan Kay definiu assim. Mas até ele admite hoje que o que ele descrevia e chamou de orientado a objeto na verdade é orientado a mensagem. E fora de OOP isto sempre existiu e chamou-se de abstração. E aí tem a briga sobre ser válido encapsular com *getter* e *setter* ou não.

Provavelmente programar orientado a objeto mesmo seja utópico, aí cada um tem seu jeito de aceitar isso.

O que eu tenho certeza é que muitas pessoas fazem *design* muito ruins porque só sabem seguir as regras que não lhes ajudam em nada, elas só as decorou e não entendeu a motivação.

## Conclusão

OOP não é entendido pelas pessoas e isso tem a ver com a forma como se ensina o assunto e como o conceito foi criado. Muito do que as pessoas acreditam ser OOP na verdade é só bom *design* de código, isso quando na verdade é um *design* ruim mas a pessoas acham bom porque decorou receita de bolo errada. Por isso sempre termino minhas palestras com:

> Uma mentira repetidas 1000 vezes não a torna verdadeira

Isso tem a ver com a ideia propalada por Joseph Goebbels. Não estou dizendo que proponentes de OOP sejam nazistas, viu? :P

Eu sei que dá pra responder melhor, provavelmente mostrando exemplos, quem sabe um dia eu o faça, mas eu tinha que responder aqui pelo menos para deixar claro que não é simples determinar isso quanto algumas acham.

Answer (score 3):

É difícil dizer o que é certo ou errado, pois tudo depende de um contexto, entretanto na orientação a objetos existem alguns tópicos. Algumas coisas que podem ajudar são:

- Evitar classes gigantes (também conhecidas como god class).
- Separar as partes do software em componentes com uma responsabilidade bem definida.
- Criar objetos para representar as partes que compõem um projeto.
- Utilizar composição para fazer os objetos trabalharem em conjunto (Injeção de dependência é uma opção para fazer isso).

Enfim, existem diversos tópicos, citei alguns que acho importante. Comece tentando entender alguns concetos e seja critico em relação ao seu próprio código. Orientação a objetos é um assunto complexo e muito conceitual.

Answer (score 1):

## (reflexão) Minha ideia é procedural ou orientada a objetos quando estou codificando?

Entendo que você quer uma orientação para seu uso enquanto está programando e, de repente, se pergunta, estou programando preceduralmente ou compatível com o paradigma de orientação a objetos? Você quer saber se o que está codificando, em um dado momento, para um dado "trecho" de código é orientado a objetos ou procedural, ou foi "dominado" por qual estratégia. Convém esclarecer que, enquanto está programando, também está realizando projeto detalhado (alguns dizem *low level design*) e a pergunta faz todo sentido. Adicionalmente, a resposta abaixo está acima do nível léxico ou sintático do código produzido, ou seja, tem como foco a semântica do código em questão, em vez das construções oferecidas por linguagens de programação.

- Se não está empregando objetos e nem tampouco seu código está sendo organizado por meio de trocas de mensagens entre eles, então provavelmente não está usando efetivamente POO. Provavelmente, nos seus pensamentos, não há um grafo de objetos entre os quais as responsabilidades estão adequadamente distribuídas.
- Se está pensando em uma sequência de passos que resolve um determinado problema, um algoritmo, um fluxograma, e segue este script, então provavelmente está programando de forma procedural. Você segue uma receita, organiza seu código em rotinas, e mesmo que façam parte de uma mesma classe, as rotinas estão ali quase que acidentalmente, apenas dividem a receita em partes menores.
- Se a coesão é baixa e o acoplamento é alto, então seguramente não faz uso efetivo de OO.

Por fim, observe que a produção efetiva de um projeto orientado a objetos demanda esforço significativo. Talvez alguém possa fazer isso "naturalmente", mas parece mais verossímil ser resultado de um esforço intencional. A intenção é esclarecer que não se trata de uma simples escolha, entre uma e outra, há um esforço mental a ser realizado e, dependendo dele, o código correspondente estará mais próximo de um código procedural ou orientado a objetos.

Answer (score -1):

Quando você chama uma procedure diretamente sem enviar uma mensagem a um objeto especifico para que ele cuide disso você esta sendo procedural.

Quando você tocar em propriedades de um objeto fora da classe do próprio objeto você esta sendo procedural.