# Como usar o namespace na criação de uma classe?

Tags: php, namespace, php-autoload

Estou trabalhando num projeto que foi criado em php (5.3) sem nunhum framework.
Estou precisnado usar uma classe de conexão ao banco de dados que eu mesmo desenvolvi.
O nome dessa classe será `db`, mas uma outra classe `db` já existe no projeto.
Então para não haver conflitos vou usar o namespace na que estou criando.

Estava olhando a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) e não ficou muito claro para mim como eu deveria usar o path no namespace até minha classe.
Essa é a estrutura que tenho no meu site:

```
/
folder1/
folder2/
  file2.1.php
  file2.2.php
folder3/
classes/
  db.php
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php
includes/
  _antes.php
```

Gostaria de saber como faço o name space de `db.php`.

Assim está correto?

```
namespace ../classes/

class db {
   ...
}
```

### Nota:

Estou usando um autoloader no `index.php` que pode carregar a classe cada vez que o objeto for chamado. (O código do autoloader está no exemplo de uso da classe)

### EDIÇÂO

A sua pergunta foi identificada como possível duplicata de outra pergunta. Se as respostas ali não resolverem o seu problema, por favor edite para explicar em detalhe as partes da sua pergunta que são diferentes.

Para o pessoal do controle que sugeriu [resp1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/como-funciona-namespaces-no-php) e [resp2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163660/namespace-com-php) como solução à minha pergunta.

Essas duas respostas mostram o que são e comparam namespaces e autoloads. A minha pergunta é "Como usar o namespace na criação de uma classe?" e não "o que são namespaces?".

### Agora fazendo um update dos meus testes:

Segundo a árvore de diretórios acima, criei a classe `db.php` dentro do folder `classes/`. Dentro da classe criei o namespace assim `namespace classes;`

Quando tento instanciar a classe de dentro do arquivo _antes.php tenho o seguinte erro no browser:

Dentro de **includes/_antes.php**

```
use classes\db;
$db = new db();

Fatal error: Class 'classes\db' not found in C:\Users\myname\Documents\projects\mysite\public\includes\_antes.php on line 15
```

Ou seja, eu não sei se o erro é decorrente da maneira como namespace foi usado na classe ou se foi um erro de como a classe foi chamada, dando o path até o namespace. Tente usar use ..\classes\db; de dentro de **includes/_antes.php** e não funciona.

Continuo com dúvida.

Fim do update.

Embora não seja necessário, vou deixar a classe para quem achar útil:

```
<?php

/**
 * Description of db
 *
 * @author zwitterion
 * 
 * Throwing an Exception http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php
 * Reference - http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pdo-exec-insert-update-delete
 */
class db {

    public static $debugMode;
    public static $dsn;
    public static $username;
    public static $password;
    public static $db;
    public static $conn;
    public static $arrConnAttr; //Array of connection attributes. Ex: ["PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", "PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION"]
    public static $pathLog; //Path to save the erro log files. Ex:$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myDirRootProject/LogError"
    public static $arrCatchConnResult; //Results of the Catch process
    public static $die; //If we set $setValues["die"]=NULL, during the object initialization, errors will not stop the process. 
    public static $sql; //Will store the sql string


    /**
     * 
     * @param array $setValues
     * ex:<br>
     * $setValues = [<br>
     *     "server"      => "",<br>
     *     "dsn"         => "",<br>
     *     "username"    => "",<br>
     *     "password"    => "",<br>
     *     "db"          => "",<br>
     *     "arrConnAttr" => "",<br>
     *     "pathErroLog" => "",<br>
     *     "die"         => "TRUE/FALSE",<br>
     *     "sql"         => "",<br>
     *     "debugMode"   => "TRUE/FALSE"<br>
     * ]
     * 
     * Ex:<br>
     * $db = new db(["die"=>TRUE,"debugMode"=>TRUE]);
     * $db = new db(["server"=>"1"]); Will search for server1 credentials
     * $db = new db(["server"=>"2"]); Will search for server1 credentials
     * or
     * $db = new db(); Will connect to default server with default credentials
     * $db = new db(["debugMode"=>TRUE]); If "debugMode"=>TRUE the die() (breaking process) will be sit to TRUE
     * 
     */
    public function __construct(array $setValues = NULL) {

       //Initialize the object 
       self::init($setValues);

        try {



            $dns = self::$dsn;

            $username = self::$username;

            $password = self::$password;

            $db = self::$db;



            self::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dns; dbname=$db", "$username", "$password"); //Now private $conn is a PDO object

            self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        }// End of try
        catch (PDOException $e) {//If had some error. The PDO object ($this->conn) could not be created. Throw an error. 


            self::$arrCatchConnResult = self::saveLogMsg(["exceptionObjc"=>$e,"sql"=>self::$sql]);

            $msg = self::$arrCatchConnResult["displayMsgHTML"];

            self::$conn = null;

            if (self::$die) {

                die($msg);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param array $setValues
     * ex:<br>
     * $setValues = [<br>
     *     "server"      => "",<br>
     *     "dsn"         => "",<br>
     *     "username"    => "",<br>
     *     "password"    => "",<br>
     *     "db"          => "",<br>
     *     "arrConnAttr" => "",<br>
     *     "pathErroLog" => "",<br>
     *     "die"         => "TRUE/FALSE",<br>
     *     "sql"         => "",<br>
     *     "debugMode"   => "TRUE/FALSE"<br>
     * ]
     * 
     * Ex:<br>
     * $db = new db(["die"=>TRUE,"debugMode"=>TRUE]);
     * $db = new db(["server"=>"1"]); Will search for server1 credentials
     * $db = new db(["server"=>"2"]); Will search for server1 credentials
     * or
     * $db = new db(); Will connect to default server with default credentials
     * $db = new db(["debugMode"=>TRUE]); If "debugMode"=>TRUE the die() (breaking process) will be sit to TRUE
     * 
     */
    private static function init(array $setValues=NULL) {          

        /*
         * Variable array $arrInitDefault is used to initialize default values to the object;
         * If array $setValues is not NULL its values should override the default values;
         */
        #Default host credentials
        $arrInitDefault["dsn"] = "defaultHost";
        $arrInitDefault["username"] = "defaultUserName";
        $arrInitDefault["password"] = "defaultPassword";
        $arrInitDefault["db"] = "defaultDBname";

        $arrInitDefault["arrConnAttr"] = ["PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", " PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION"];
        $arrInitDefault["pathLog"] = dirname(__FILE__) . "/Log/Error"; //Default path to dir. Note: error pathLog can be "/Log/Error/UserName" or "/Log/Error/UserId", etc
        $arrInitDefault["die"] = FALSE;//By default it will not break the web site, but will still generate the error file. $db = new db(["die"=>FALSE]);
        $arrInitDefault["sql"] = FALSE;        
        $arrInitDefault["debugMode"] = FALSE;



        //Catch dynamic sit values.
        if (!is_null($setValues)) {
            $arrInitDefault = array_merge($arrInitDefault, $setValues);            

            //If "debugMode"=True others debug variables must to be true.
            if($arrInitDefault["debugMode"]){
                $arrInitDefault["die"] = TRUE;             
            }

            if(isset($setValues['server'])){
                if($setValues['server']=="1"){
                    $arrInitDefault["dsn"] = "defaultHost";
                    $arrInitDefault["username"] = "defaultUserName";
                    $arrInitDefault["password"] = "defaultPassword";
                    $arrInitDefault["db"] = "defaultDBname";
                }
                elseif ($setValues['server']=="2") {
                    $arrInitDefault["dsn"] = "hostToServer2";
                    $arrInitDefault["username"] = "userNameServer2";
                    $arrInitDefault["password"] = "passwordServer2";
                    $arrInitDefault["db"] = "dbNameServer2";
                }
            }
        }

        //After merge, initialaze private variables with result merged $setValues
        self::$dsn = $arrInitDefault["dsn"];
        self::$username = $arrInitDefault["username"];
        self::$password = $arrInitDefault["password"];
        self::$db = $arrInitDefault["db"];
        self::$arrConnAttr = implode(",", $arrInitDefault["arrConnAttr"]);
        self::$pathLog = $arrInitDefault["pathLog"];
        self::$sql = $arrInitDefault["sql"];

        self::$die = $arrInitDefault["die"];
        self::$debugMode = $arrInitDefault["debugMode"];

    }


    /**
     * This function will save the logFile inside the LogFolder and will return an array with some messages
     * @param array $saveLogsParam
     * @return type array
     * 
     * <br>
     * That is the expected @param array:
     * <br>
     * $saveLogsParam = [<br>
     * "sql"    => "SELECT * FROM foo ..."<br>
     * "exceptionObjc"    => PDOException object #e<br>
     * ]   
     * <br>
     * That is the @return array:
     * [<br>
     * "status"    => "The create message process status",<br>
     * "msg" => "Some message about the status",<br>
     * "displayMsgHTML"    => "The message to be displayed in HTML format ...",<br>
     * "displayMsgTXT"    => ">>> ... the message to be displayed in TXT format ...",<br>
     * ] 
     * 
     */
    public static function saveLogMsg($saveLogsParam = NULL) {

        xdebug_break();

        $year = date("Y");
        $month = date("M");
        $day = date("d");
        $dt = date("d.M.Y_H.i.s");
        $pathLog = self::$pathLog . "/" . $year . "/" . $month . "/" . $day . "/";

        if (!is_dir($pathLog)) {
            mkdir($pathLog, 0777, true);
        }//If is not a dir, create it.


        //Generate the HTML and .txt displayMessages trough self::getDisplayMessage($getDisplayMsgParam)
        $getDisplayMsgParam = [
            "dt" => $dt,
            "exceptionObjc" => $saveLogsParam['exceptionObjc'],
            "sql" => $saveLogsParam['sql']
        ];


        $getDisplayMessage = self::getDisplayMessage($getDisplayMsgParam);



        $createLogFile = [
            "dt" => $dt,
            "pathLog" => $pathLog,
            "displayMsgTXT" => $getDisplayMessage['displayMsgTXT']
        ];
        self::createLogFile($createLogFile);



        return [
            "status"=>TRUE,
            "msg"=>"The folder $pathLog is sit!",
            "displayMsgTXT"=>$getDisplayMessage['displayMsgTXT'],
            "displayMsgHTML"=>$getDisplayMessage['displayMsgHTML']
        ];

    }

    /**
     * This function will create the LogFile in a .txt format and store it in a specified $pathLog.
     * @param array $param
     * 
     * <br>
     * That is the expected @param array:
     * <br>
     * $param = [<br>
     * "dt"    => "String - Displays date and time, like this - 28.apr.2017_18.5259",<br>
     * "pathLog"    => "String - The path where the log file will be stored.",<br>
     * "displayMsgTXT" => "String - The key "displayMsgTXT" result from getDisplayMessage() method."<br>
     * ]  
     * 
     *    
     */
    public static function createLogFile(array $param=NULL) { 

        if (!is_null($param)) {            
            $dt=$param["dt"];
            $pathLog=$param["pathLog"];
            $displayMsgTXT=$param["displayMsgTXT"];


            $f = $pathLog . "$dt.txt";
            if(self::$debugMode){
                $myfile = fopen($f, "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
            } 
            else {
                $myfile = fopen($f, "w");//Will not stop the process even if we have a issue with the query process    
            }

            fwrite($myfile, $displayMsgTXT);
            fclose($myfile); 

            return 
            [
                "status"=>TRUE,
                "msg"=>"The file $myfile was successfully created!"
            ];            
        } 
        else {
            return 
            [
                "status"=>FALSE,
                "msg"=>'Null $param was given to createLogFile() method'                    
            ];
        }        
    }

    /** 
     * @param array $param
     * @return type array
     * 
     * <br>
     * That is the expected @param array:
     * <br>
     * $param = [<br>
     * "dt"    => "28.apr.2017_18.5259",<br>
     * "exceptionObjc"    => PDOException object #e,<br>
     * "sql"    => "SELECT * FROM foo ..."<br>
     * ] 
     * <br>
     * That is the @return array:
     * [<br>
     * "status"    => "The create message process status",<br>
     * "msg" => "Some message about the status",<br>
     * "displayMsgHTML"    => "The message to be displayed in HTML format ...",<br>
     * "displayMsgTXT"    => ">>> ... the message to be displayed in TXT format ...",<br>
     * ]
     */
    public static function getDisplayMessage(array $param=NULL) {
        if (!is_null($param)) { 


        $excepObjc = $param['exceptionObjc'] ;

        $logMsg = $excepObjc->getMessage();        
        $arrStackTrace=$excepObjc->getTrace();

        $strTraceHTML="<table class='table'><thead></thead><tbody>";
        $strTraceTXT=NULL;

        foreach ($arrStackTrace as $k =>$arr) {
            $strTraceHTML.="       
                    <table class='table'>
                        <thead>
                            <th>Stack Trace [{$k}]</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>file</td><td>{$arr['file']}</td>   
                            </tr>       
                            <tr>
                                <td>line</td><td>{$arr['line']}</td>   
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>function</td><td>{$arr['function']}</td>   
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>   
                    ";
            $strTraceTXT.="                    
                    Gets the stack trace [{$k}]\n
                    file=>{$arr['file']}\n
                    line=>{$arr['line']}\n
                    function=>{$arr['function']}\n
                    ";
        }

        $strTraceHTML.="</tbody></table>";   

$displayMsgHTML = <<<EOF

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">

Date:     {$param["dt"]} <br/>

Msg:     <span class="label label-danger">{$logMsg}</span><br/>  

<kbd>Sql</kbd>: {$param["sql"]}<br/>

StackTrace: {$strTraceHTML}<br/>

</div>

EOF;

$displayMsgTXT = <<<EOF

>>>>>  Log Message:  <<<<< \n 

Date:{$param["dt"]}  \n

Msg: {$logMsg} \n  

Sql: {$param["sql"]} \n

StackTrace: $strTraceTXT \n

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

EOF;



            return 
            [
                "status"=>TRUE,
                "msg"=>'Display message was successfully created',                    
                "displayMsgHTML"=>$displayMsgHTML,                  
                "displayMsgTXT"=>$displayMsgTXT                  
            ];            
        } 
        else {
            return 
            [
                "status"=>FALSE,
                "msg"=>'Null $param was given to getDisplayMessage() method',                    
                "displayMsgHTML"=>$displayMsgHTML,                  
                "displayMsgTXT"=>$displayMsgTXT                                   
            ];
        }         
    }


    public static function get_values(array $setValues = NULL) {

        try {

            self::$sql = $setValues['sql'];

            $stmt = self::$conn->prepare(self::$sql);

            $stmt->execute();

            while ($field = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $arrResult[] = $field;
            }

            return $arrResult;
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {

            self::$arrCatchConnResult = self::saveLogMsg(["exceptionObjc"=>$e,"sql"=>self::$sql]);

            $msg = self::$arrCatchConnResult["displayMsgHTML"];

            self::$conn = null;

            if (self::$die) {

                die($msg);
            }
        }
    }



}



#How to use it?

#Use this autoload function to load the db Class when the db Object is instantieted.
#No need to use include or include once around the code!
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {              
    include './classes/'.$class_name . '.php';
});

#Now lets instantiate an $db object
$db = new db();
#or
$db = new db(["die"=>TRUE,"debugMode"=>TRUE]);

#Performing a query 
$setValues=[
   "sql"=>"select * from myTablez",
];

$result = $db->get_values($setValues);

#If we have any error that is what we will see: in the Log Folder

>>>>>  Log Message:  <<<<< 


Date:01.May.2017_19.21.24  


Msg: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hostpath.myTablez' doesn't exist 


Sql: select * from myTablez 


StackTrace:                     
                    Gets the stack trace [0]

                    file=>C:\Users\...\Documents\projects\...\public\classes\db.php

                    line=>371

                    function=>execute


                    Gets the stack trace [1]

                    file=>C:\Users\...\Documents\projects\...\public\includes\_before.php

                    line=>19

                    function=>get_values




>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163660/namespace-com-php

Comment: Na verdade não respondeu a minha pergunta. As respostas acima explicam o que são namespaces e autoloads. A minha pergunta diz respeito à composição do path do namespace - essa é a minha dúvida. Pelo que eu entendi o path do namespace é em relação ao folder imediatamente superior ao da classe e quando eu for usar essa classe tenho que fazer use path do root ate o local onde a classe esta sendo instanciada. COntinua  a dúvida.

Comment: a duplicata e a outra que também é duplicata explica essa parte do `path`, mas, sabe o que poderia fazer é ir para o meta e explicar que não concorda com o fechamento dessa questão, porque, pra você ainda ficou duvidas, eu sinceramente não importo em tirar o meu voto de duplicata. Bom eu faria isso ...