# Problema no Autoload PHP

Tags: php, php-autoload, spl, spl-autoloader-register

Estou iniciando em `POO` e `SPL` e recentemente enfrentei o seguinte problema: tenho o seguinte arquivo que faz todo o `bootstrapping` da minha aplicação `init.php`, e nele, faço o `autoload` de todas as classes do diretório **lib/**:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() 
              . PATH_SEPARATOR 
              . APP_ROOT_PATH 
              . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
              . 'lib');
spl_autoload_extensions( ".php" );
spl_autoload_register();
```

Porém, o mesmo retorna um erro, sempre dizendo que alguma das classes que eu instanciei posteriormente não foi encontrada:

> `/welcome.php - Uncaught Error: Class 'Hash' not found in /var/www/project/welcome.php:15`

Então, para debugar, fiz o seguinte código:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    $file = $className . ".php";
    //echo 'Carregando arquivo ' . $file . PHP_EOL;
    require_once $file;
});
```

E desta forma, funciona perfeitamente, todas as minhas classes são importadas! Alguém já testemunhou algo semelhante?

> welcome.php

```
<?php

session_start();

define('APP_ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));

$configFiles = glob(APP_ROOT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.php');

foreach($configFiles as $configFile){
    require_once $configFile;
}

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . APP_ROOT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib');
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
//spl_autoload_register();
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    $otherClassName = $className;
    $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    $file = $className . ".php";
    //echo 'Carregando arquivo ' . $file . ' ' . $otherClassName . PHP_EOL;
    require_once $file;
});
//echo get_include_path();


require_once 'functions.php';


require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Estrutura da pasta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [namespace com php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163660/namespace-com-php)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic segui o conceito utilizado no link que você disponibilizou, tratei os namespaces para terem os mesmos nomes dos seus diretórios e consegui resolver outros conflitos que enfrentei, mas ainda continua a persistir este problema, apenas `spl_autoload_register();` não funciona, da outra forma funciona!

Comment: poderia postar as pastas em uma imagem e o conteudo do `welcome.php`?