# Como usar namespaces sem classes com autoload do composer?

Tags: php, composer, namespace, autoload

Estou tentando usar os namespaces sem classes com o autoload do composer, porém acredito que o mesmo está falhando, por exemplo:

/Foo/Bar.php

```
namespace Foo\Bar {
    function baz() {
        echo 'Funcionou';
    }
}
```

/index.php

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';

Foo\Bar\baz();
```

Ao executar o arquivo index gera o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Foo\Bar\baz() in /[...]/basic/index.php on line 5

porém se eu incluir préviamente o arquivo:

/index.php

```
require './Foo/Bar.php';

Foo\Bar\baz();
```

Então funciona. Acredito que ao chamar `Foo\Bar\baz` ele esteja tentando incluir o arquivo `Foo\Bar\baz.php`, porém não tenho certeza

Meu autoload no `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Foo\\": "./Foo"
    }
}
```

Fiz o `dump-autoload`

O uso é num framework, onde o usuário pode criar rotas passando uma função com o seu namespace para ser executada (por exemplo, `Router::get('/foo', 'App\Foo\get');`), como, geralmente, não é preciso guardar estado, a classe se torna desnecessária. O uso da propriedade `files` do composer resolve o problema, porém não permite lazy load (carregar apenas o que é usado, ou seja, sob demanda), o que pode significar muitos arquivos incluidos pra nada

Comment: Cade o arquivo composer?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o `composer.json`? Está praticamente em branco como falei

Comment: Então, não vai funcionar se o mesmo está em branco consequentemente não carrega nada!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic alterei o arquivo como eu imagino que deveria ficar e adicoinei na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse tipo de implementação é corresponde a organização de pasta, o `namespace` deve ter o mesmo caminho da sua pasta, que não é o que acontece na sua pergunta, o correto seria criar o diretório de pasta da seguinte forma:

```
/Foo/Bar/Bar.php
```

e o seu `namespace` correspondente

```
Foo/Bar
```

no arquivo de configuração `composer.json` configure da seguinte forma:

```
{
    "name": "Virgilio/Pack",    
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Foo\\Bar\\": "Foo/Bar"
        }   
    }
}
```

ou seja, a primeira chave é o `namespace` e a sua atribuição o caminho da pasta (ou pastas), rode agora o comando `php composer.phar dump`.

Outro porém é que essa implementação é para `load` de `classes` e não de funções, o de funções é na chave `files` que deve ser implementado com o caminho do arquivo, exemplo:

```
{
    "name": "Virgilio/Pack",    
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Foo\\Bar\\": "Foo/Bar"
        },
        "files": [
            "Foo/Bar/Bar.php" 
        ]
    }
}
```

e rode o comando `php composer.phar dump`.

Vale lembrar que nesse arquivo `Bar.php` o correto é só ter funções ou `classes` e também se for ter somente funções não precisa colocar `namespace`, mas, nada impede, acredito dificultar a digitação na hora da programação.

---

**Resumo** configuraria assim:

```
{
    "name": "Virgilio/Pack",    
    "autoload": {           
        "files": {
            "Foo/Bar/Bar.php" 
        }   
    }
}
```

e utilizaria como o `namespace` assim:

```
echo \Foo\Bar\baz();
```

ou retiraria esse `namespace` que julgo desnecessário no arquivo `Bar.php` e digitaria:

```
echo baz();
```

e tente fazer um código mais limpo e menos complicado para utilização.

---

Outro exemplo básico: [namespace com php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163660/namespace-com-php/163662#163662) e uma leitura recomendavel [The composer.json Schema - PSR-4#](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4)

Comment: Porém adicionando na lista de `files` será todos carregados juntos no início, e não conforme for utilizando (se utilizado), certo?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, espero que tenha ficado mais claro, agradeço se poder ajudar

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam você disse **porém não permite lazy load (carregar apenas o que é usado, ou seja, sob demanda), o que pode significar muitos arquivos incluídos pra nada**, com funções tem que ser feito pelo `files` é assim que o arquivo de configuração demonstra na sua documentação. Se for classe tem o efeito de carregamento preguiçoso, apesar que `classe` geralmente colocamos uma em cada arquivo para funcionar, já função são várias em um arquivo (pode ser uma também, mas, geralmente colocamos várias), porque você não muda a estratégia então.?

Comment: continuando ... @GuilhermeCostamilam trabalhando com classes, já que que é um framework, bom qual é o framework?

Comment: https://costamilam.github.io/Alpha. Se eu criasse uma função própria para o autoload, poderia funcionar?

Comment: é um micro framework, olha só se pode utilizar o que eu fiz sem problema, vai ter que ser assim mesmo com `files` configurado @GuilhermeCostamilam

Comment: Poderia então só adicionar uma observação na sua resposta que o composer não suporta lazy load sem classes?

Comment: Seria um erro eu falar isso, porque, o `composer` é o gerenciador de pacotes e o PHP que é responsável em carregar as funcionalidades. @GuilhermeCostamilam Se eu coloco isso a minha resposta fica errada, a sua pergunta original tem a explicação de como é a melhor forma de subir as funções.

Answer (score 1):

Eu ainda não entendi o porque de utilizar dessa forma, você quer apenas chamar a função correto? Se for isso seria mais fácil criar um helper e através dele você criar a função e chamar a mesma.

Para isso, eu adicionei a seguinte linha no meu composer indicando o local do meu helper.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/helper.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta, espero que tenha ficado mais claro