# ERRO NOT FOUND - PHP

Tags: php

ERRO:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AlunoMasculino\Aluno' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fullstrack\PHP OO\Exercicios\Projeto-Escola\AlunoMasculino.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Fullstrack\PHP OO\Exercicios\Projeto-Escola\Universidade.php(2): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fullstrack\PHP OO\Exercicios\Projeto-Escola\AlunoMasculino.php on line 7**

```
<?php 

namespace Aluno;

 class Aluno{
    public $codigo;
    public $nome;
    public $cpf;

    function __construct(){

    }
    public function getSexo()
    {
        return $this->sexo;
    }

    public function isApto($apto){
        return true;
    }

    public function setSexo($sexo)
    {
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
    }


}



?>
```

```
<?php
namespace AlunoMasculino;
include 'Aluno.php';



class AlunoMasculino extends Aluno{
    public $numeroCarteiraMilitar;



    public function setNumeroCarteiraMilitar($numeroCarteiraMilitar){
        $this->numeroCarteiraMilitar = $numeroCarteiraMilitar;
    }

    public function isApto($apto){


        return true;
    }


    public function getSexo($sexo)
    {
        return $this->sexo;
    }


}



?>
```

```
<?php
require_once 'AlunoMasculino.php';
require_once 'Aluno.php';

//Namespace
//use AlunoMasculino\AlunoMasculino ;

$AlunoMasculino = new AlunoMasculino();

//codigo uid
$token = md5(uniqid(""));

//Aluno, codigo e cpf
$AlunoMasculino->nome = "Aluno";
$AlunoMasculino->codigo = $token;
$AlunoMasculino->cpf = "000.000.000.00";
$AlunoMasculino->setSexo("Masculino");
$AlunoMasculino->getSexo();




 ?>
```

ESSE ULTIMO É O ARQUIVO UNIVERSIDADE, NAO ESTOU CONSEGUINDO CHAMAR O ALUNO MASCULINO INFORMANDO Q ELE NAO ENCONTROU A CLASS ALUNO

Comment: Você sabe como funciona o *namespace*? Você definiu a classe `Aluno` dentro do *namespace* `Aluno`, mas está tentando utilizá-la dentro do *namespace* `AlunoMasculino`. Basicamente você implementou `Aluno\Aluno` e chamou `AlunoMasculino\Aluno`, que não existe.

Comment: estou estudando ele nesse momento, é um exercicio, por isso a duvida, entendeu ? ou seja  no caso eu queria usar ele em outra classe, pq o namespace praticamente so é usado qd classes tem o mesmo nome, certo ?

Comment: Talvez seja conveniente ler [Como funciona namespaces no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104420/5878) | [Namespaces e Use quando usar e para que servem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151487/5878)

Comment: ok, obrigado, nao sei se eu apago essa pergunta ou se marco como visto